# Intentional removal of limbs for prosthetics

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a short story I read in the last year where an engineer designs an advanced prosthetic limb. He loses a limb in an industrial accident; it is replaced by his design. He realizes that being unbalanced limits the effectiveness so he intentionally loses another limb. I believe he ends up losing all four in order to get the prosthetics.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you read it in a magazine, anthology, or something else?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the Jonathan Coulton song "Better".  :-)

Comment: It also sounds a bit like Edgar Allan Poe's *The Man Who Was Used Up*.

Comment: Not the story you're looking for, but you might like Bernard Wolfe's novel "Limbo" on a related theme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be Max Barry's *[Machine Man](http://maxbarry.com/machineman/)*. Originally published as a web-based novel, the print version is expanded from the original. To borrow from the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Man_%28novel%29):

> Charles Neumann is a mechanical engineer working at Better Futures, a military research company. After losing one of his legs in a hydraulic clamp, he begins to tinker with leg prosthetics. The replacements he builds are so advanced that he amputates his remaining leg in order to make full use of them.

[image: Cover image]

Comment: Of course I get beat to the punch. Good find. :P

Comment: @TrishLing: Heh. It's a very distinctive book. I read about it on TVTropes first, and had to get a copy from the library.

Comment: Thanks much; as soon as I saw the answer it came flooding back to me :-)

Answer (score 3):

A short story, not a novel, right? There's a short story, "[Man Made](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1275349)", by Albert Teichner where a man slowly over the course of his life has bit by bit of his body replaced by prosthesis, until all that is left is his brain. And then he gets a brain tumor. And then he's given an option.